# android get activity context in abstract base class

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-context

I am creating an abstract base class to keep my navigation drawer code in one place and want to implement an `onClickListener` on my app title (defined in the toolbar) to start my launch activity

I am using the following code :

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.toolbar_title:
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            return;
    }
}
```

The app works properly, but I read somewhere that one must not use the Application context to start new activities. However, android studio doesn't let me use any other context apart from `getApplicationContext` and `getBaseContext`, maybe because this class is abstract.

Which context should I use then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [`Context.getApplicationContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getApplicationContext()) and [`ContextWrapper.getBaseContext()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContextWrapper.html#getBaseContext()). Both have in common to be defined on a context instance. In your case it's even an `Activity`.

So you could even use `this` as a context to start your `MainActivity`. This is even better, because with any other context type you' have to include the flag `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to start a new activity.

If you get errors by using `this` for a context, it's because you define your `OnClickListener` as anonymous inner class which of course isn't a context. For that you'd have to write `MyBaseActivity.this` instead. This references the outer class instance.

Comment: Hey, one question : `this` in the base class will refer to the context of the currently running activity? As in the output of `this` or `MyBaseActivity.this` will be same as calling getContext in that (derived) activity?

Comment: @sudshekhar There's nothing like `getContext()`. But `this` always refers to the instance of an object. This would just be your running activity.

Answer (score 2):

Well, one of the ways can be: You can define an abstract method in your `BaseActivity` class:

```
abstract void launchMainActivity();
```

And call this method in your click listener:

```
@Override 
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()){
        case R.id.toolbar_title:
            launchMainActivity();
            return; 
    } 
}
```

The sub-classes can then implement this method as:

```
@Override
void launchMainActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks I like your approach too but I chose the other answer because this approach still requires an implementation in all the derived classes (thus kind of violates DRY).

Comment: @sudshekhar alright man, but isn't it what you started with in the first place?